# Can Forge Autodesk Recap API convert a point cloud data to surface data?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-realitycapture

I have point cloud data which is in the form of generally huge files (RCS, RCP). I am looking for an option where I can get files with surface data possibly with reduced files size. Is it possible to view this kind of large data in Forge Viewer?